# Several http Amazon ports

Tags: http, iis, amazon-ec2

I'm setting up a server on Amazon where you would like to have multiple sites on the same instance.

I configured on the IIS server in each site a door, but the firewall Amazon only allows me to access port 80 outside.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you have multiple sites configured on different ports.

You need to find the security group of your instance in the ec2 console. Then look at the inbound rules. You will need to enter a rule for each port or a range of ports, corresponding to the IIS ports.

[image: inbound rules]

See this link for more details

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html